# Why are certain permissions hidden in developer.android.com

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Android permissions are listed here:

Manifest.permission http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

In AndroidManifest.xml at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml, there are few extra permissions that are not listed in the Manifest.permission.
These hidden permission come with the `@hide` in thir description in AndroidManifest.xml.

Why there permissions are hidden?
Can these permissions still be used by applications if it is allowed for third party applications?

Comment: Edited the question. Changed the repeated link.

Comment: most of the hidden permissions have a comment that explains why they are hidden, the others are dangerous. Regarding the hidden safe ones, I don't know, I think it could be because you don't actually need to declare them to do what they allow.

Answer (score 2):

Those type of permissions are for **core system applications** (from manufacturers) and/or low-level enough to be AOSP-specific.

Example:

```
<!-- @hide Allows low-level access to tun tap driver -->
<permission android:name="android.permission.NET_TUNNELING"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
```

This permission is reserved for Android's AOSP source code. It falls under `SYSTEM_TOOLS` permission group and can only be used when **signed with the same signature as the OS**.

The API team simply decided not to expose this permission, and I doubt anyone (except core system applications) can use them or even declare them be using them -- **hidden APIs = private APIs**.